# How to make 2 different character switch in the same scene and also rigs possible?

Tags: rigging, objects, armature, workflow, scene

I'm not very well at explain. But How do if I want make 2 different head switch in same scene. for example, One head for human, other head for monster. So that I want make look like he transform into monster. Also, Is this possible for rigs to link in same scene? I don't know how to do. you can click this video for example. https://youtu.be/6xr_9Ce2Ylc?t=137

Comment: are you talking about a morphing effect or simply make an object disappear and the other appear? If you're just talking about visibility there are several ways to do it I guess, you could simply put the 2 head meshes in the same object and use for example the Mask modifier?

Comment: Sorry I'm late, Not something  that I'm looking. Don't worry about that. just forget it. Maybe I should  details more.